# Tie standard Woocommerce orders to Woocommerce Subscriptions

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

We had a legacy system that used Woocommerce but not Woocommerce Subscriptions, we've since migrated to Woocommerce Subscriptions but we have a tonne of standard Woo orders that we'd like to tie to subscriptions.

Via the database, if I find the subscription in the postmeta table, I can manually change `_subscription_renewal_order_ids_cache` to include the order id so it becomes the following:

```
a:2:{
  i:0;i:143052;
  i:1;i:143049;
}
```

(I've added the second line)

On the order itself if I add the meta `_subscription_renewal` with the subscription id that then ties the order to the subscription.

Can this be done programmatically? I've done the following but it's not outputting the meta (so therefore I can't amend it).

```
global $wpdb;

// get all subscriptions IDS
$subscriptions_ids = $wpdb->get_col("
    SELECT ID  FROM {$wpdb->prefix}posts
    WHERE post_type LIKE 'shop_subscription'
");

// Loop through subscriptions Ids
foreach( $subscriptions_ids as $subscription ){
    // Get an instance of the WC_Subscription object
    $subscription = new WC_Subscription( $subscription );

        $subscription_id = $subscription->get_id();
        $subscription_email = $subscription->get_billing_email();

        echo $subscription->get_meta('_subscription_renewal_order_ids_cache');

        echo "<pre>";
        print_r( $subscription );
        echo "</pre>";
}
```

I've not gone any further with the code until I'm able to output and amend the post meta.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be done by going through orders and adding the meta line:

```
$order = wc_get_order();
$order->update_meta_data( '_subscription_renewal', $subscription_id );
$order->save();
```

With `$subscription_id` being the ID of the subscription you'd like to tie the order to.